# How to remove path and stuff in terminal VS Code

Tags: python, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

When I am running a python program for example :

```py
print("hello world")
```

I get too many texts in the terminal (VS Code)

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Dimuth De Zoysa\Desktop\Python_projects> & "C:/Users/Dimuth De Zoysa/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe" "c:/Users/Dimuth De Zoysa/Desktop/Python_projects/main.py"
hello world
PS C:\Users\Dimuth De Zoysa\Desktop\Python_projects>
```

But I really wanted is something like this :

```
hello world
```

So, How can I remove those paths & nonsense text ?

Comment: they are not nonsense, and you can't remove them

Answer (score 1):

First of all, they are not meaningless text, they show the execution command of the script file, which can also ensure that the script can be executed normally in any directory. We should get used to the way it works.

If you must get clean output, install the [**Code Runner**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension, add the following to the *settings.json*, and execute the script with `Run COde`

```json
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": false,
    "code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true,
    "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
```

[image]

*If there is no special need, please do not use **Code Runner**. Using **Python** extensions is the best way.*

Answer (score -2):

Try following which will skip the first two lines and then print lines that do not start with a PS

```
$filename = 'c:\temp\test.txt'

$filteredData = Get-Content -path $filename | Select-Object -skip 2 | Select-String -NotMatch "^PS"
$filteredData
```

Comment: The question is about _Python_ code, and how running it from Visual Studio Code presents in the latter's integrated terminal. Your answer is a confusing distraction.